# WebView how to detect button is clicked or not

Tags: javascript, android, button, webview

In my app I display a third party page whose code I cannot access using WebView.
In that page there is a button. I want to display some ads when that button is not.

Is there any way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your java object to the javascript page and call a method on it from javascript when button is clicked. This can be done through `@JavascriptInterface`.

Refer this for the details: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html